# Coordinate geometry problem - Find the value of 'a'

Tags: calculus, quadratics, coordinate-systems

Find the number of values of 'a' for which the curves $y= ax^2 + ax + \frac{1}{24}$ and $x = ay^2 + ay + \frac{1}{24}$ touch each other.

**MY ATTEMPT:**

Since both the curves are the inverse of each other, they must be images about the line $y = x$. Therefore, for them to touch each other, they must touch $y=x$

Thus I solved the line with one of the curves and then applied the condition for equal roots ($D=0$)

So I got two values of a as $\frac23$ and $\frac32$

However the correct answer is 4 values of a. So I checked out the graph of the curves (by substituting 'a' with the other answers) and discovered that there is also a possibility of them touching *on* the line $y=x$ without touching the line itself as shown here

[image]

How do I find the other two values of 'a' in this scenario?

Comment: Tried equating the tangents yet?

Comment: Both curves are inverse of each other,  how ?

Comment: Yeah. But you don't know the value of a and x at the point, so you can't solve for either

Comment: @A---B, because if you subsitute y for x and x for y in the second equation/first equation, you get the other curve

Comment: @AjaySubramanian. Does your curves even satisfy $f(g(x))=x$?

Comment: Yeah. You can try that if you want:)

Comment: But, I wouldn't because two curves are obviously  inverses of each other when one's an image of the other about y=x

Comment: @AjaySubramanian For $x = 0$, $y = 1/24$. But from second curve, for $y = 1/24$, $x = a/576 + a/24 + 1/24$.

Comment: @A---B, that doesn't make sense. I meant switch x for y (the actual variables)

Comment: What you did is just substitute points in the second equation. That would only work if the curves were the same

Comment: It would not work for inverses since inverses represent the curve when axes are switched with each other i.e when you try to obtain the object variable in terms of the subject variable

Comment: @AjaySubramanian Let $y = \sin(x)$ and $x= \arcsin(y)$. Now if I plug $x = pi/4$ I get $y = 1/\sqrt{2}$ and if I plug $y = \sqrt{2}$ in the second equation I get $x = \pi/4$. Are you saying $\sin x$ and $\arcsin x$ are not inverse of each other ?

Comment: I'm not saying that. What you did now is correct. In the first example you cited, you substituted 1/24 in both equations. Rather, you should have substituted 1/24 in one of them and 24 in the other

Comment: A function and its inverse need not intersect on y=x, for example $y=-x^3$ and $y=-(x)^{\frac{1}{3}}$.

Comment: Exactly. They just have to be images about y=x